# Can I dispatch two reducers in one function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a function where I'm calling two reducers. When I just call the `clearTmpFood` reducer, it works but when I call both together, I get a blank screen. Am I not allowed to call 2 reducers in one function?

In my index.js file:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const add_food = async () => {
  dispatch(clearTmpFood()); // clear the state
  dispatch(clearFoodIndex());
}
```

In my questionnaire.js file:

```
const initialState {
  // initial state for tmpFood is here too
  foodIndex: ""

const QuestionnaireSlice = createSlice({
  name: "QUESTIONNAIRE",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    clearFoodIndex: (state) => ({
      ...state,
      foodIndex: { ...initialState.foodIndex }
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: What error do you get in the dev tools?

Comment: I get `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: It's ok to run two `dispatch`es one after another. You get the blank page because of the error. To fix this error we will need much more code from your app.

Comment: Yea but it only shows up when I call that reducer. If I take it out, I don't get that error. It might be because of the other reducer that is being called with it. Let me update my code

Comment: You've initialised `foodIndex` as an empty string. It doesn't make sense to use `...initialState.foodIndex`. There's also a big difference between `foodIndex` and `FoodIndex`

Comment: Ya sorry I had that as mitake..I updated it. I want to reset foodIndex to an empty string because I am checking somewhere else if it has a value. If it does, then I display the value, otherwise something else

Comment: I don't think you understood my comment. In your `clearFoodIndex` reducer, you're setting `foodIndex` to `{ ...initialState.foodIndex }`. What exactly do you think is the result of `{ ..."" }`? Answer: It's an empty object `{}`

Comment: I am resetting the state. The state gets updated at one point, so when I am calling this reducer I want to reset the state of `foodIndex` back to ""

Comment: **This can be closed as a typo**. All you need is `foodIndex: ""` in your `clearFoodIndex` reducer (or `foodIndex: initialState.foodIndex`)

Comment: Ohh I see. I had the syntax wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to only call  clearFoodIndex()?

If it's not working, then i maybe think that your error is from your reducer or action.